# upload streaming to WCF IIS 7 hosted service not working

Tags: wcf, wcf-streaming

I have a wcf service I am setting up to run under IIS 7. I have the service set to streaming for the transfermode.
When I self host the service in a console application every thing seems to work ok.  But when the client connects to an iis hosted service it seems to be buffering, and the client eventual times out.  I have used fiddler to determine that this client time out happens before the http request is even made.

Here is the servers binding.

```
var binding = new CustomBinding();
            binding.Elements.Add( new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement()
            {
                MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10
            } );

            var secBinding = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
            secBinding.AllowInsecureTransport = true;
            binding.Elements.Add( secBinding );
            binding.Elements.Add( new HttpTransportBindingElement()
            {
                TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue,

            } );
```

And the client binding:

```
var binding = new CustomBinding();
            binding.Elements.Add( new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement()
            {
                MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10
            } );

            var secBinding = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
            secBinding.AllowInsecureTransport = true;
            binding.Elements.Add( secBinding );
            binding.Elements.Add( new HttpTransportBindingElement()
            {
                TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue,
                MaxBufferSize = 400
            } );
```

As an aside the connection is timing out because the stream is infinite and the server should read the first few bytes and then close the stream.

Comment: There seems to be no resolution to this problem. See this thread in the MSDN forums where someone is trying to do the same thing. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/cfe625b2-1890-471b-a4bd-94373daedd39

Comment: @MikeSchenk you should change your comment to an answer. That thread says it is a problem that may be fixed in .Net 4.5

Answer (score 2):

Recently, we had the same issue. When you host your service under IIS, no matter if you enable streaming or not, your service will buffer the entire message prior to sending it.   The reason for this, is that it appears as though WCF does not set the Response.BufferOutput to "false" (default is true), when streaming is enabled on a service. A workaround can be found here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jclarknet/archive/2008/02/14/wcf-streaming-issue-under-iis.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you closing the Stream in the client? If true, try closing just in the service side.
Also, verify if its a OneWay operation.
Can you post the both binding nodes, for the endpoints?

Comment: The stream is closed on the server.  But the request never makes it that far.